# Mate: window not maximising on correct monitor

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, 17.04, ubuntu-mate

I am on ubuntu mate 17.04. I have dual monitor setup. Both are working properly. I have set DP-5 as primary. I have nvidia drivers installed also.

[image]

But when i am on a window on DP-1-1 and double click on its windows bar to maximize it, the window maximizes in the DP-5 screen. Also why is right screen named DP-1-1, shouldn't it be DP-4? IS that the issue? I cannot figure out why the widow will not maximize in its own screen.

Also when i press ctrl+space to launch synapse, it always appears in DP-1-1 only.

What settings should i change? Please let me know if other info is needed.